# How to know when NSURLSession work is finished?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I work with `NSURLSession` and usually I have some code like this:

```
var a = 2
...
let urlRequest = NSMutableRequest(URL:NSURL.URLWithStrin("http://localhost"))
let session = NSURLSession(...)
...
var dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest({data:NSData!, ...) in
// for example data is equal 3
a = a*data
})
dataTask.resume()

a = 4
```

So `a` always will be equal `4` not `6` because for NSURLSession need some time for request data from server etc. I can stop at `dataTask.resume()` and just wait when it finished and only after this continue to work code?